# Trying to open tiff file in python getting TiffPage 0: <COMPRESSION.CCITT_T6: 4> not supported

Tags: python, tiff

I trying to open TIFF file and getting following error:

> TiffPage 0: <COMPRESSION.CCITT_T6: 4> not supported

I using tifffile python library as follows:

```
import tifffile as tiff 
img = tiff.imread('/tmp/my_filey.tiff') 
img
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your file uses bi-level fax compression. You could try resaving it with, say LZW, compression, by using **ImageMagick** in your shell/terminal with `magick /tmp/my_filey.tiff -compress LZW /tmp/new_filey.tiff` If using older v6 **ImageMagick**, replace `magick` with `convert`

Comment: From the tifffile documentation: "Specifically, CCITT and OJPEG compression, ... are not implemented."  TIFF isn't a specific file format, it's just a framework for defining file formats.  There is no such thing as a TIFF reader that can handle every single TIFF file in the world, there are just too many possible variations.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Any python library to handle this case? My target is convert this tiff file to a png or jpg.

Comment: Maybe use Dropbox or Google Drive to share a sample image so we can try.

Comment: It is confidential data. Any idea where to start?

Comment: I think I created a t.6 TIFF correctly, and was able to read it with PIL/Pillow. I imagine `wand` can read them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **PIL/Pillow** installed along with `libtiff` and am able to read a T6 TIFF with:

```
fron PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.tif')
```

I imagine [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand//) will be able to read your T6 TIFF too, since it is based on **ImageMagick** which had no problems. I'm not sure how desperately you want to write Python, but you can just convert a T6 TIFF to a PNG or JPEG in your Terminal/shell with **ImageMagick** using:

```
magick input.tif output.png
```

Of course, you could *"shell out"* from Python and do exactly the same thing with `subprocess()`.

---

As you were unable to supply a T6 TIFF, I made one with **ImageMagick** in Terminal:

```
magick -size 500x500 gradient: -compress Group4 image.tif
```

You can check the compression with `exiftool` using:

```
exiftool image.tif

...
Compression     : T6/Group 4 Fax
...
```

You can also create a T6 TIFF with `tiffcp` which comes with `libtiff` by copying a non-T6 TIFF and specifying T6 compression:

```
tiffcp -c g4 nonT6.tif T6.tif
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved inspired on your answer.